# SFBusyIndicator doesn't show up

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

I'm trying tu use SFBusyIndicator in Xamarin IOS c# but it doesn't show up...

```
        SFBusyIndicator busyindicator = new SFBusyIndicator();

    public TesourariaViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        busyindicator.Frame = this.View.Bounds;
        busyindicator.AnimationType = SFBusyIndicatorAnimationType.SFBusyIndicatorAnimationTypeGear;
        busyindicator.ViewBoxHeight = 200;
        busyindicator.ViewBoxWidth = 200;
        busyindicator.Title = (NSString)"Loading...";
        busyindicator.FontFace = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(10, UIFontWeight.Thin);
        busyindicator.Center = this.View.Center;
        this.View.Add(busyindicator);

    }
```

I have a button touchup event in the ViewDidLoad where i call busyindicator.IsBusy = true, but nothing happens, the busy indicator doesn't show up!

Guess i'm doing something wrong... or missing something...
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I never used Syncfusion components but from what I can see on their [getting started page](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ios/sfbusyindicator/getting-started), component initialization is quite different compared to yours: there is something wrong with view adding in your UIVIewController.

Try to create and show indicator in `ViewDidLoad` method (just for a test)

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    SFBusyIndicator busyindicator = new SFBusyIndicator();
    this.AddSubview(busyindicator);
    busyindicator.AnimationType=SFBusyIndicatorAnimationType.SFBusyIndicatorAnimationTypeBattery;
    busyindicator.TextColor=UIColor.RED;
    busyindicator.ViewBoxHeight=20;
    busyindicator.ViewBoxWidth=20;
    busyindicator.IsBusy=True;
}
```